# Convert select statement to Group by

Tags: mysql, sql

i create a view (see below)
the problem is that i get dublicat rows and with UNION they are deselected, 
i dont want to use UNION ALL

so my question is, how can i rewrite the two "select .. " to a Group by expression,Group by: YEAR, Month
and get the same result as UNION ALL

```
 CREAT VIEW v_test_rerytering (.......) AS
 select
   F.ALDER          
   age,
   cast(P.AR as VARCHAR2(4)) year,  
   ccast((P.MANAD)as VARCHAR2(2)) month,    
   cast(K.KON_KOD as VARCHAR2(50)) SEX,
   cast('Extern' as VARCHAR2(50)) R_KOD,
   F.NR_REK                 
   REK
 from test.Table_anstallda F join test.PERIOD P on P.PERIOD =
 F.PERIOD

 union

 select
   F.ALDER                                   
   age,
   cast(P.AR as VARCHAR2(4)) year,  
   ccast((P.MANAD)as VARCHAR2(2)) month,    
   cast(K.KON_KOD as VARCHAR2(50)) SEX,
  cast('Extern' as VARCHAR2(50)) R_KOD,
  F.NR_dism                
  REK
from test.Table_anstallda F join test.PERIOD P on P.PERIOD_SN =
 F.PERIOD   ;
```

Comment: First fix the query because this query contains alot off typing errors.. and i don't think you are using MySQL. MySQL doesn't have a VARCHAR2 datatype..

Answer (score 0):

You should join PERIOD on PERIOD or PERIOD_SN and use COALESCE or a CASE statement to set the field for the REK column.

This is the coalesce version, which may not work depending on your data:

```
SELECT F.ALDER age
    ,cast(P.AR AS VARCHAR2(4)) year
    ,ccast((P.MANAD) AS VARCHAR2(2)) month
    ,cast(K.KON_KOD AS VARCHAR2(50)) SEX
    ,cast('Extern' AS VARCHAR2(50)) R_KOD
    ,REK = coalesce(F.NR_REK, F.NR_dism)
FROM test.Table_anstallda F
JOIN test.PERIOD P 
    ON P.PERIOD = F.PERIOD 
    OR p.Period = f.PERIOD_SN
```